# How could I group these markers when there will be more than 10000 of them?

Tags: java, php, android, json, google-maps

I have a map, on which I place markers. How could I group these markers when there will be more than 10000 of them? I found examples only with local JSON but I have the latlng from the server in a form:

```
[
  {
    "name": "hereName",
    "adr": "hereAdress",
    "latlng": [
      44.444444444,
      55.555555555
    ]
  }
]
```

Code:

```
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (map == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        if (map != null) {
            new MarkerTask().execute();
        }
    }
}

private class MarkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private static final String SERVICE_URL = http://exm.com/latlng.php";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return json.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        try {
            // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)
                );

                // Create a markers
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                        .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                        .snippet(jsonObj.getString("adr"))
                        .position(latLng));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: yes, but there local json

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, why you think it matters whether the JSON is local or not. For example, you could download your 10,000-entry JSON file to the device. At that point, it too is local.

Comment: Json will be constantly updated on the server. I think that every time to download and use locally not very well

Comment: Then you are going to be largely on your own. Existing clustering solutions work because *they have access to all the locations*. Your solution would somehow need to "cluster" locations, *without* having all the locations. Presumably, this will require your server to come up with clusters itself, and serve JSON with information about the clusters, which you will then render yourself by one means or another.

Comment: if instead of this line 

InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.localJSON);

substitute JSON from the server, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ClusterManager class  of Google maps for this. It will show the markers in a cluster instead of showing them differently

Comment: wmk, a solution in the next my comment

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
private GoogleMap map;
private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
double lat;
double lng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (map == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, mapFragment.getMap());
        mapFragment.getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        mapFragment.getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        if (map != null) {
          new MarkerTask().execute();
        }
    }
}

private class MarkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private static final String SERVICE_URL = http://exm.com/latlng.php";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return json.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                List<MyItem> items = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
                lat = jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0);
                lng = jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1);

                items.add(new MyItem(lat, lng));
                mClusterManager.addItems(items);
           }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }
```